# 12setinterval can't stop and I can't change speed it with offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a new developer & I am learning js for 4months. I have 2 problems with programming my website in setinterval first issue is clearu=intervall doesn't work and the second is the speed of my left_num has not changed.
I want to make slide show blocks auto and manual. I don't know what can I do. please help me.

```js
creat_btn();

function creat_btn() {
  var i;
  var move = document.getElementById("newsdiv");
  var moving = document.getElementById("news");
  for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    move.innerHTML += '<button id="new5"  onclick=""><p>' + i + '</p></button>';
  }
}
var iv = setInterval(moving_fun, 1000);
var a = 0;



function moving_fun() {
  a++;
  var left_num = move.offsetLeft;
  move.style.left = left_num + "px";
  console.log(a, left_num);
  left_num += 80;
  if (left_num <= move.style.height) {
    clearInterval(iv);
  }
}

}

function plusbl(n) {}
```

```css
#news {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  top: 102.5%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: outset rgb(255, 0, 0) 10px;
}

#newsdiv button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin: 20px 2.5px 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#newsdiv {
  background: none;
  position: relative;
}

#newsdiv button p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 90%;
  left: 45%;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.nextbtn,
.prevbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 3%;
  left: -5%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px 7px 16px 0px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.nextbtn {
  left: 100%;
}

.prevbtn:hover,
.nextbtn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.main_grid button {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(32, 255, 32, 0.726), rgba(44, 255, 255, 0.781), rgba(229, 255, 0, 0.87));
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1/12;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 7/12;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 4/7;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 4/12;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 1/12;
  grid-row: 4/4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>site-tr01</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_grid">
    <button class="one">1</button>
    <button class="two">2</button>
    <button class="three">3</button>
    <button class="four">4</button>
    <button class="five">5</button>
    <button class="six">6</button>
    <div id="news">
      <div id="newsdiv"></div>
      <a class="prevbtn" onclick="plusbl(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="nextbtn" onclick="plusbl(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

12setinterval can't stop and I can't change the speed with offsetLeft

Comment: please State the problem clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some bugs in your code - problems with the functions scope, so that you can't do `clearInterval`, here is fixed one. Do you need something like this? Btw I've changed some logic just for reference, there you can do it as you wish

```js
creat_btn();

var a = 0;
var iv;

function creat_btn() {
  var i;
  var move = document.getElementById("newsdiv");
  var moving = document.getElementById("news");
  
  iv = setInterval(() => {
    moving_fun(move);
  }, 1000);


  for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    move.innerHTML += '<button id="new5" onclick=""><p>' + i + '</p></button>';
  }
}




function moving_fun(move) {
  a++;
  var left_num = move.offsetLeft;
  move.style.left = left_num + "px";
  console.log(a, left_num, move.offsetWidth);
  left_num += 80;
  if (left_num >= move.offsetWidth) {
    clearInterval(iv);
  }
}

function plusbl(n) {};
```

```css
#news {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  top: 102.5%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: outset rgb(255, 0, 0) 10px;
}

#newsdiv button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin: 20px 2.5px 0 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px 40px 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

#newsdiv {
  background: none;
  position: relative;
}

#newsdiv button p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 90%;
  left: 45%;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.nextbtn,
.prevbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 3%;
  left: -5%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px 7px 16px 0px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.nextbtn {
  left: 100%;
}

.prevbtn:hover,
.nextbtn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.main_grid button {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(32, 255, 32, 0.726), rgba(44, 255, 255, 0.781), rgba(229, 255, 0, 0.87));
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1/12;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 7/12;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 4/7;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 4/12;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 1/12;
  grid-row: 4/4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>site-tr01</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main_grid">
    <button class="one">1</button>
    <button class="two">2</button>
    <button class="three">3</button>
    <button class="four">4</button>
    <button class="five">5</button>
    <button class="six">6</button>
    <div id="news">
      <div id="newsdiv"></div>
      <a class="prevbtn" onclick="plusbl(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="nextbtn" onclick="plusbl(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help,now I want to change left_num faster than now but it cant change in consol

Comment: set interval less than 1000 ms, i.e 100

Comment: you are right but I want more traverse its position than now  at this time 1s

Comment: ok, then alter this: `left_num += 80;` change 80 to some higher value. 80 here is pixels number to offset your object each 1000 ms